# Definition of exponentiation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading the "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin (available in PDF [here](https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf)): at page 10 the statement of theorem 1.21 says: "For every real $x>0$ and every integer $n>0$ there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^n=x$."

Now, apart from the actual proof of that theorem which is super-clear, I'm not convinced with the definition of $x^n$: the operation which are in the definition of field are $\cdot$ and $+$; previously, at page 6, the text says "one usually writes $x^2$, $x^3$... in place of $xx$, $xxx$," so that I understand that $x^2$ is only a particular notation for an iterated multiplication, but I'm not happy with the definition $x^n:=\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot ...\cdot x}_\text{n times}$.

What does *n times* mean? What's the relation between *n times* and $n \in \mathbb{N}$? How else can I define $x^n$?

Comment: How about recursive definition $x^n=x \cdot x^{n-1}$ for $n>0$ and $x^0=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you multiply $ n $ copies of $ x $ together. You're writing $ x $ down $ n $ times in that definition.

The relation is that you're trying to define what integer exponents mean, and you can do so by writing $ x $ down $ n $ times in a product as shown.

It doesn't change much, but you can also define it like this:

$$ x^n := \prod_{i=1}^{n} x $$

As Zoran Loncarevic points out, you can define it recursively, like $ x^0 := 1 $ and $ x^n := x \cdot x^{n - 1} $.

You can also define it in more difficult terms, such as a special case of dealing with real exponents, though you'd have to define that, which is more complicated.